# Windows 10 problems with USB audio device

Tags: windows-10, usb

I have a USB hub where my usb headset, speaker device, mouse, keyboard and more is connected. When working from home I plug this into my worklaptop.

On my home machine, running Windows 11, everything works great. I get all my audio devices. I can switch between them and everything is OK.

But on my worklaptop (Lenovo P15 Gen2, running windows 10 pro) I cant use the speaker device. The speaker device is listed, and has the right name so the driver got installed correctly(?). If I select it as the audio output device volume is set to 0 and when I try to change this is immediately jumps back to 0.

I've checked Windows event manager and there are only two informational events that the device was configured and then started.

Any tips?

Comment: Does the hub need power and if so, is it getting power from the laptop USB connection?

Comment: The hub has power @n00dles. Works great with my stationary machine. Not my worklaptop (thru its). Today the my headset isnt usable, but my speaker device is